# Unable to append a list of values to specific keys of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

1) I first map the key names to a dictionary called main_dict with an empty list (the actual problem has many keys hence the reason why I am doing this)

2) I then loop over a data matrix consisting of 3 columns

3) When I append a value to a column (the key) in the dictionary, the data is appended to wrong keys.

Where am I going wrong here?

**Minimum working example:**
Edit: The data is being read from a file row by row and does not exist in lists as in this MWE.
Edit2: Prefer a more pythonic solution than Pandas.

```
import numpy as np
key_names = ["A", "B", "C"]
main_dict = {}
val = []
main_dict = main_dict.fromkeys(key_names, val)

data = np.array([[2018, 1.1, 3.3], [2017, 2.1, 5.4], [2016, 3.1, 1.4]])

for i in data:
    main_dict["A"].append(i[0])
    main_dict["B"].append(i[1])
    main_dict["C"].append(i[2])

print(main_dict["A"])

# Actual output: [2018.0, 1.1, 3.3, 2017.0, 2.1, 5.4, 2016.0, 3.1, 1.4]

# print(main_dict["A"])
# Expected output: [2018.0, 2017.0, 2016.0]
# print(main_dict["B"])
# Expected output: [1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
# print(main_dict["C"])
# Expected output: [3.3, 5.4, 1.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using numpy (which is a heavy weight package for what you are doing) I would do this:

```
keys = ["A", "B", "C"]
main_dict = {key: [] for key in keys}

data = [[2018, 1.1, 3.3], [2017, 2.1, 5.4], [2016, 3.1, 1.4]]

# since you are reading from a file
for datum in data:
    for index, key in enumerate(keys):
        main_dict[key].append(datum[index])

print(main_dict) # {'A': [2018, 2017, 2016], 'B': [1.1, 2.1, 3.1], 'C': [3.3, 5.4, 1.4]}
```

Alternatively you can use the built-in `defaultdict` which is a tad faster since you don't need to do the dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict
main_dict = defaultdict(list)

keys = ["A", "B", "C"]
data = [[2018, 1.1, 3.3], [2017, 2.1, 5.4], [2016, 3.1, 1.4]]

# since you are reading from a file
for datum in data:
    for index, key in enumerate(keys):
        main_dict[key].append(datum[index])

print(main_dict)
```

Lastly, if the keys really don't matter to you, you can be a little more dynamic by coming up with the keys dynamically starting from `A`. Thus allowing lines to have more than three attributes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
main_dict = defaultdict(list)

data = [[2018, 1.1, 3.3], [2017, 2.1, 5.4], [2016, 3.1, 1.4]]

# since you are reading from a file
for datum in data:
    for index, attr in enumerate(datum):
        main_dict[chr(ord('A') + index)].append(attr)

print(main_dict) # {'A': [2018, 2017, 2016], 'B': [1.1, 2.1, 3.1], 'C': [3.3, 5.4, 1.4]}
```

Comment: The data was appended for a reason since it is read from a file row by row. You solution is elegant however I am not sure list(zip(*data)) is applicable here?

Comment: That slightly changes things... Give me a minute.

Comment: Is there a more pythonic solution than using Pandas?

Comment: @bwrr 1) See my update. 2) I wouldn't consider using an external module "pythonic", especially NumPy and Pandas which are quite large and thus add a lot to the project. Those packages do have their use-cases (especially in AI and machine learning) and Numpy is extremely fast at doing matrix logic; however, you aren't doing that here and are thus just adding large packages to your code for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was wondering if you can kindly explain why my previous solution was not assigning the lists properly to the keys? It would help me understand where I was going wrong in my logic perhaps.

Comment: @bwrr `from_keys` didn't do what you expected it too because each key pointed to the same `val`, the reason being because `val` is a mutable object thus all keys referenced the same object. Change it to `{key: [] for key in key_names}` and your solution will work. This is referred to as the "case of the mutable default".

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the [common gotchas of python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/). It will help you with some of these annoying things that you won't experience till you write a lot of python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
main_dict = main_dict.fromkeys(key_names, val)
```

The same list val is referenced by all the keys since python passes reference.